# word cloud -Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am replicating [this](http://alstatr.blogspot.kr/2014/03/r-text-mining-on-twitter-prayformh370.html) word cloud tutorial, but I get:

Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I do not really understand what is going on on each step of the code, but I think the problem might be related to the matrix produced having different rows or columns. This is the code I am using:

```
install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64", "httr"))

library(devtools)
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)

##
api_key= "xxxxxx"
api_secret= "xxxxxx"
access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret= "xxxxxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

searchTwitter("amlo")

library(twitteR)
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)
install.packages("wordcloud")
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

mh370 <- searchTwitter("#PrayForMH370", since = "2014-03-08", until = "2014-03-20", n =             1000)
mh370_text = sapply(mh370, function(x) x$getText())
mh370_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(mh370_text))

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(
  mh370_corpus,
  control = list(
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stopwords = c("prayformh370", "prayformh", stopwords("english")),
    removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE)
)

m = as.matrix(tdm)
# get word counts in decreasing order
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE) 
# create a data frame with words and their frequencies
dm = data.frame(word = names(word_freqs), freq = word_freqs)
wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order = FALSE, colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default behavior for the TermDocumentMatrix function from the tm pacakge is that is only tracks words that are longer than **three** characters.

So just add this parameter **wordLengths=c(0,Inf)** to the control list of TermDocumentMatrix:

```
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(
     mh370_corpus,
     control = list(
     wordLengths=c(0,Inf),
     removePunctuation = TRUE,
     stopwords = c("prayformh370", "prayformh", stopwords("english")),
     removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE) )
```