# How set worldcloud in R to only track words >3 characters in length to prevent error message

Tags: r, tm

I am a beginner at R and am trying to create a word cloud.  My code and the error message that I am unable to fix are below:

I imported a csv file consisting of tweets, made a list from the column in the csv file that contained the text from the tweets, then tried the code below which gave me the error message above:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stripWhitespace)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
```

Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

In this post it states that this error message is due to having words that are less than 3 characters in length: [word cloud -Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113372/word-cloud-error-in-strwidthwordsi-cex-sizei-invalid-cex-valu)

My code is different than in this example so I tried to set the characters to greater than 3 in length via the line of code below to avoid the above error message.  However this returns the new error message below:

```
myCorpus <- which(length(myCorpus)>3)
```

Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to fix this.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Length doesn't return the number of characters in a string, but the number of elements in the vector.

Based on the documentation, one way to filter words 3 or less characters is the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(myCorpus)) {
    myCorpus[[i]] <- removeWords(myCorpus[[i]], ".{3}?")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help however I am still getting the same error message after modifying my last line of code to: myCorpus <- which(nchar(myCorpus)>3).                                                                             The error message is still: Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')".  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Because myCorpus is not a string vector, but a TermDocumentMatrix object.  See the edit :)

Comment: I appreciate the help but after using the new line of code I now get a new error message:Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve the error above but the similar code below successfully creates a word cloud without the error message:

```
file<-read.csv("file",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)

file<-Corpus(VectorSource(file))

file<-tm_map(file, PlainTextDocument)

file<- tm_map(file, removePunctuation)
file<- tm_map(file, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
file<- tm_map(file, stemDocument)

wordcloud(file, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)
```